# Problem with handling 'basic authentication' modal in selenium automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, basic-authentication, alerts, modalpopup

In one site, when I click a link it should open a login page. But, before loading the page it gives a popup that looks like an alert but in dev tools, it shows nothing. Also, the automation scripts return a 'no such alerts' error. I also can't find any locator for that popup using tools like Selenium IDE or selectors hub. Can anyone please help me understanding what type of element is this and how to handle this?

Note: if I cancel the popup then the login page loads.

[image]

**UPDATE:** When the modal appears the URL has a parameter like this-
*auth?client_id=[id]&redirect_uri=[url]&state=[a-hex-value]&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=[a-hex-value]*

Comment: Tried with different solutions, non worked. But, the AUTH modal didn't appear when I used Firefox browser. Still don't know what's wrong with chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's authentication modal. You can deal with it by using login and password, being defined in url `https://username:password@URL`

Example:

```
https://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth
```

[Documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http-basic-authentication-url-with-in-password#:%7E:text=We%20can%20do%20HTTP%20basic,%3A%2F%2Fusername%3Apassword%40URL.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried this solution but no luck. The modal is still loaded. Note: in my case, the username is an email containing a @.

Comment: Try replace @ in login (user email) to `%40`

Comment: Tried with it but still no luck.

Comment: can you please suggest a way to cancel it? I cannot find anything mentioned about canceling in the documentation.

Comment: Try to authenticate via page interface

`await page.authenticate({'username':'yourEmail', 'password': 'yourPassword'});`

before `goto`
<br>

[Reference](https://dev.to/sonyarianto/puppeteer-quick-tip-how-to-do-basic-authentication-2pe7)